# What is difference between choosing OCRnA and ICRn in timer/counter CTC mode in ATMega2560?

Tags: microcontroller, timer

I can't find any difference since both function the same role: define the top value so that timer will reset when reach this value. Both have its interrupt flag and interrupt service routine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is that choosing `ICRn` will allow `OCRnA` to control the `OCnA` pin at a value lower than `TOP`.